# loading/calling Javascript function with ajax request on android's webview

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, url, webview

By the title itself, I want to know if it is possible to call a Javascript function with ajax request using android's webview. Because I'm getting error on my log cat:

Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier,
sometimes uncaught reference error:  is not defined at null

This is how I call the javascript function:

webview.loadUrl("javascript:searchPath("+ position + "," + destination +")" );

where position and destination are variables

where in my html file where function searchPath(var1, var2) contains ajax request

Comment: webview.loadUrl("javascript:searchPath('"+ position + "','" + destination +"')" );

I knew it now. Yes, it is possible, I'm only getting those web console error because my parameters are string and it should be single quoted.